# bootstrap datepicker not working after postback

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown and a textbox . When the page loads first time . The datepicker is working. After button click also the datepicker is working fine. But when the dropdown selected index is changed the datepicker is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `dropDownList` does the `postback` then you can you call `pageload()` method like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function pageLoad() {
            $('.datepicker').nepaliDatePicker();
        }
</script>
```

Hope it works. make sure to change cssClass and names of datepicker

Answer (score 0):

write your js code (for example : $('.date-picker').datepicker()) in **script** tag not in a function or document ready function.

Codes in script tag always run even after postback and your input DatePicker makes agian.